# Prove that if $a\mid c$, $b\mid c$, $a\nmid b$, then $a\mid \frac{c}{b}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My idea:

$\forall a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$, if $a\nmid b$ and $a\mid c$ and $b\mid c$, $\exists k_1,k_2\in\mathbb{Z}$, such that $c=ak_1$ and $c=bk_2$. Since $a\nmid b$, $\exists q,r\in\mathbb{Z}, b=aq+r$

Comment: $a=6$, $b=10$, $c=30$.

Comment: This is not true, if you assume the stronger condition $\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)=1$ then it becomes true.

Answer (score 1):

Not true.

If $b=c$ then
this becomes
$a | c, a \ne c
\implies a | 1$.